# ¿Necesito el total de coincidencias de palabras entre 2 cadenas con MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ya logré traer las Categorías en las que al menos encontró (1) una palabra, sin importar el orden (en una tabla MyiSAM con index Fulltex)...... Ahora el problema es saber el total de coincidencias que tuvo en cada registro o el que más tuvo palabras. Que en éste caso en particular de la foto es la última...

El SQL es:

```
SELECT id,nombre FROM prod_categoria2 where match(nombre) against ('altavoces Bose ultima 5 generacion latinoamerica colombia' in boolean mode)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El SQL es: SELECT id,nombre
FROM prod_categoria2 
where match(nombre) against ('altavoces Bose ultima 5 generacion latinoamerica colombia' in boolean mode)

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta. Los comentarios son temporales. Además te recomiendo leer: **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La consulta te muestra por defecto el registro con más ocurrencias de primero.

De modo que poniendo un `LIMIT 1` obtendrás únicamente el registro que más ocurrencias tuvo.

Ahora bien, saber cuántas ocurrencias hubo de cada cosa imposible no es, pero difícil sí.

En el ejemplo (consulta 2) se muestra un ranking de la cantidad de ocurrencias en cada fila. En base a eso habría que hacer un cálculo.

La documentación explica más o menos cómo hacerlo **con una sola palabra** y es algo complicado. Mucho más complicado será tratándose de varios criterios de búsqueda. Sugiero que revises el apartado: [Relevancy Rankings for InnoDB Boolean Mode Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html). Otra dificultad es que los cálculos con el motor MyISAM al parecer son menos seguros.

Aquí te dejo el código de prueba.

La consulta 1 muestra el registro que tuvo más ocurrencias.

La consulta 2 muestra un score de ocurrencias calculadas.

Espero te sirva.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/CPLAW30860)

```
CREATE TABLE test_20170805 (
    id  SERIAL,
    dato VARCHAR(70)
);

ALTER TABLE test_20170805 ADD FULLTEXT(dato);


INSERT INTO test_20170805 (dato) 
                 VALUES 
                 ('Altavoces'),
                 ('Cables de Altavoces'),
                 ('Altavoces Colombia'),
                 ('Bose Carlos Doris'),
                 ('Generaciones Altavoces'),
                 ('Última Bose Colombia')
            ;

-- Obtener la que tiene más ocurrencias usando LIMIT 1; --


SELECT id, dato FROM test_20170805
WHERE MATCH (dato) 
AGAINST ('altavoces Bose ultima 5 generacion latinoamerica colombia' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 1;


-- Obtener un ranking ordenado de mayores a menores ocurrencias --

SELECT id, dato, 
       MATCH (dato)  AGAINST ('altavoces Bose ultima 5 generacion latinoamerica colombia' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM test_20170805 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

---

**`Resultado`**

```
--Consulta 1

id  dato
6   Última Bose Colombia

--Consulta 2


id  dato                       score
6   Última Bose Colombia       1,06080877780914
3   Altavoces Colombia         0,258652836084366
4   Bose Carlos Doris          0,227644696831703
1   Altavoces                  0,0310081318020821
2   Cables de Altavoces        0,0310081318020821
5   Generaciones Altavoces     0,0310081318020821
```

Comment: Excelente, Mil gracias!!!

Comment: @ChristianMuñozSalazar por favor **[acepte la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Saludos.